# Cannot get npm installed app to be present in final Docker image

Tags: docker, npm

I have added installation of the Vega tools to the docker-asciidoctor Dockerfile and they are present when running the bats tests, but when I run the image they are no longer present.

I am quite new to Docker.

I have also tried some variations of adding the dir node_modules to the path, but nothing works.

In all cases the directory where the Vega tools are installed to is simply not in the image.

I am adding the Vega tools like this:

```
...
  && npm install --build-from-source -g vega-cli vega vega-lite vega-embed \
  && echo `which vl2vg` \
...
```

which provides this output:

```
...
/usr/bin/vl2png -> /usr/lib/node_modules/vega-lite/bin/vl2png
/usr/bin/vl2svg -> /usr/lib/node_modules/vega-lite/bin/vl2svg
/usr/bin/vl2vg -> /usr/lib/node_modules/vega-lite/bin/vl2vg
/usr/bin/vg2pdf -> /usr/lib/node_modules/vega-cli/bin/vg2pdf
/usr/bin/vg2png -> /usr/lib/node_modules/vega-cli/bin/vg2png
/usr/bin/vg2svg -> /usr/lib/node_modules/vega-cli/bin/vg2svg
...
/usr/bin/vl2vg
```

just as one would expect.

And the test that one of the tools are there looks like this:

```
@test "vl2vg is installed and in the path" {
  docker run -t --rm "${DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME_TO_TEST}" which vl2vg
}
```

That passes.

I would expect the Vega tools to be available in the image when I do the following:

```
docker run -it --entrypoint /bin/sh asciidoctor/docker-asciidoctor
/documents # which vl2vg
which: no vl2vg in (/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin)
```

Given the output from the build of the image I would have expected to see `/usr/bin/vl2vg` and `/usr/lib/node_modules` is not there.

For completeness here is the Docker file and the steps taken:

```
FROM alpine:3.9

LABEL MAINTAINERS="Guillaume Scheibel <guillaume.scheibel@gmail.com>, Damien DUPORTAL <damien.duportal@gmail.com>"

ARG asciidoctor_version=2.0.9
ARG asciidoctor_confluence_version=0.0.2
ARG asciidoctor_pdf_version=1.5.0.alpha.17
ARG asciidoctor_diagram_version=1.5.16
ARG asciidoctor_epub3_version=1.5.0.alpha.9
ARG asciidoctor_mathematical_version=0.3.0
ARG asciidoctor_revealjs_version=2.0.0

ENV ASCIIDOCTOR_VERSION=${asciidoctor_version} \
  ASCIIDOCTOR_CONFLUENCE_VERSION=${asciidoctor_confluence_version} \
  ASCIIDOCTOR_PDF_VERSION=${asciidoctor_pdf_version} \
  ASCIIDOCTOR_DIAGRAM_VERSION=${asciidoctor_diagram_version} \
  ASCIIDOCTOR_EPUB3_VERSION=${asciidoctor_epub3_version} \
  ASCIIDOCTOR_MATHEMATICAL_VERSION=${asciidoctor_mathematical_version} \
  ASCIIDOCTOR_REVEALJS_VERSION=${asciidoctor_revealjs_version}

# Installing package required for the runtime of
# any of the asciidoctor-* functionnalities
RUN apk add --no-cache \
    bash \
    curl \
    ca-certificates \
    findutils \
    font-bakoma-ttf \
    graphviz \
    inotify-tools \
    make \
    openjdk8-jre \
    py2-pillow \
    py-setuptools \
    python2 \
    ruby \
    ruby-mathematical \
    ttf-liberation \
    unzip \
    which

RUN addgroup --system appgroup && adduser -S appuser -G appgroup

WORKDIR /data/



# Installing Ruby Gems needed in the image
# including asciidoctor itself
RUN apk add --no-cache --virtual .rubymakedepends \
    build-base \
    libxml2-dev \
    ruby-dev \
  && gem install --no-document \
    "asciidoctor:${ASCIIDOCTOR_VERSION}" \
    "asciidoctor-confluence:${ASCIIDOCTOR_CONFLUENCE_VERSION}" \
    "asciidoctor-diagram:${ASCIIDOCTOR_DIAGRAM_VERSION}" \
    "asciidoctor-epub3:${ASCIIDOCTOR_EPUB3_VERSION}" \
    "asciidoctor-mathematical:${ASCIIDOCTOR_MATHEMATICAL_VERSION}" \
    asciimath \
    "asciidoctor-pdf:${ASCIIDOCTOR_PDF_VERSION}" \
    "asciidoctor-revealjs:${ASCIIDOCTOR_REVEALJS_VERSION}" \
    coderay \
    epubcheck:3.0.1 \
    haml \
    kindlegen:3.0.3 \
    pygments.rb \
    rake \
    rouge \
    slim \
    thread_safe \
    tilt \
  && apk add --update npm \
#  && npm -g config set user root \
  && apk --no-cache --virtual .canvas-build-deps add \
        build-base \
        cairo-dev \
        jpeg-dev \
        pango-dev \
        giflib-dev \
        pixman-dev \
        pangomm-dev \
        libjpeg-turbo-dev \
        freetype-dev \
    && apk --no-cache add \
        pixman \
        cairo \
        pango \
        giflib \
#  && npm -g config set user root \
  && npm config set user 0 \
  && npm config set unsafe-perm true \
  && npm install --build-from-source -g vega-cli vega vega-lite vega-embed \
  && echo `which vl2vg` \
#    && apk del .canvas-build-deps \
  && apk del -r --no-cache .rubymakedepends

ENV PATH /data/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
ENV NODE_PATH /data/node_modules/

# Installing Python dependencies for additional
# functionnalities as diagrams or syntax highligthing
RUN apk add --no-cache --virtual .pythonmakedepends \
    build-base \
    python2-dev \
    py2-pip \
  && pip install --upgrade pip \
  && pip install --no-cache-dir \
    actdiag \
    'blockdiag[pdf]' \
    nwdiag \
    Pygments \
    seqdiag \
  && apk del -r --no-cache .pythonmakedepends

USER appuser

WORKDIR /documents
VOLUME /documents

CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

The build command is (lifted from the `Makefile`):

```
DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME ?= docker-asciidoctor
DOCKERHUB_USERNAME ?= asciidoctor
DOCKER_IMAGE_TEST_TAG ?= $(shell git rev-parse --short HEAD)
build:
    docker build \
        -t $(DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME_TO_TEST) \
        -f Dockerfile \
        $(CURDIR)/
```

Testing is with:

```
test:
    bats $(CURDIR)/tests/*.bats
```

where one of the tests is the one mentioned above.

Comment: Why are you not using the same variable to run the commabd: ${DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME_TO_TEST}? If you tested it and it worked then you should also use it. Can you try and get back with the result? Change asciidoctor/docker-asciidoctor with ${DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME_TO_TEST}

Comment: (Meta: I've removed the external link to GitHub - that will change over time, and thus when future readers refer to this question, it may not reflect the state of the problem you have now. If the question after my edit does not offer enough information to readers to repro the problem, would you edit it so that it does? I wonder if maybe more of the Dockerfile needs to be shown?)

Comment: What do you get if you run `docker run -it asciidoctor/docker-asciidoctor ls /usr/bin` - does that list the binaries you are after? If so, I wonder if their execute bits are not set, or maybe they have incorrect ownership?

Comment: @halfer the link was actually useful. In any case... If you run the command that way you don't know if the latest version was pushed. Building the image locally, tagging it and running would be more reliable. Which is I think the steps he is missing.

Comment: @Mihai: if the link was useful, then the question is off-topic until it is repaired - thanks for letting me know. We require a [mcve] here i.e. everything readers need to see must be in the question itself. This ensures that questions will last in perpetuity.

Comment: I agree with you that the wrong image might be being run - good point. user3495510, what command are you using for your `docker build`?

Comment: @halfer you were right - all I had to do was to use the right image and then I got action. Now my problem with this is no longer the `vl2*` tools missing, but rather that I don't know how to use the vega diagrams in a way that asciidoctor-diagram accepts. I'll do some reading up on how the docker toolchain is working so I avoid these problems going forward.

Comment: all, please let me know if we need more context to make this problem useful to others, or if we have to change things dramatically to make it useful, or even delete the whole thing - I have something that seems to work, but I'd like to leave something behind for others in a similar situation as me.

Comment: @lehoff: looks good to me, thanks for the edits - close vote retracted. Would you add a self-answer below?

Answer (score 0):

The root cause for this was that I wasn't using the image that I had just built since I wasn't tagging the image.

```
docker tag asciidoctor/docker-asciidoctor:442d4d0 asciidoctor/docker-asciidoctor:latest
```

and then things worked.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for this! - super helpful, especially the tip about `npm install -g canvas` and vega-cli using the `npm - g config set user root`.

I was building from a different base image: mhart/alpine-node. Here's the Dockerfile that worked for me..

```
FROM mhart/alpine-node:12.16.2

WORKDIR /app

COPY *.jar .

RUN apk add --no-cache \
    python2 \
    build-base \
    g++ \
    cairo-dev \
    jpeg-dev \
    pango-dev \
    bash \
    imagemagick

RUN npm -g config set user root \
 && npm install -g canvas \
 && npm install -g vega vega-lite vega-cli

# USER root
# RUN apk update
# RUN apk fetch openjdk8
# RUN apk add openjdk8
```

The four lines commented out at the each are for installing java as well.